# Run integration tests simultaneously in Nightwatch.js + Saucelabs in same browser instance

Tags: integration-testing, nightwatch.js, saucelabs

I am trying to run certain integrations test cases using Nightwatch.js and Saucelabs. Currently, for each test case, a new browser window opens and due to this, the test cases are taking a long time.

I need to run the test cases in the same browser window and display test case result for each test case on SauceLabs.

Below is the code similar to what I need to run.

```js
module.exports = {
  beforeEach: (browser, done) => {
    //login
  },

  'Test-1': browser => {
       browser
        .page
        .testPage()
        .navigate()
        .end()
  },

  'Test2': browser => {
       browser
        .page
        .testPage()
        .navigate()
        .end()
  },

  afterEach: (browser, done) => {
    //logout
  },
}
```

If I remove .end() from Test-1, Saucelabs runs the test in one browser, but only shows test result with name Test-2

Answer (score 0):

Nightwatch handles the starting and stopping of webdriver automatically by default, but you can disable this and manage it yourself by setting the webdriver start_process configuration option to false in your nightwatch.json file:

```
"webdriver" : {
  "start_process": false
}
```

Nightwatch reference documentation: https://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted#configuration

However, you probably shouldn't do that.

First of all, it means more work for you -- you will have to manage starting and stopping sessions yourself in each test spec, including passing in the configuration.

Secondly, sessions in Sauce Labs are meant to be started and stopped for each test.  Sauce will only recognize 1 completed test -- passed or failed for each session.

Finally, it's not a good practice to lump together tests in a single session -- your browser may be in an unexpected state, with different cookies and cache, and your app may have lingering settings from a previous tests.  By creating a new session in Sauce Labs you ensure that everything is "clean" and you can be sure to reproduce any scenario exactly.

I understand the desire to try to save time because it takes longer to start each session individually, as well as to go through whatever preparatory steps are needed to get to a certain state within your application.  But you'd be better off being able to configure that state by calling an API, setting a cookie, or whatever it takes rather than having your browser in an unknown state.

This is why Nightwatch restarts the browser between tests automatically.